# pandas read csv is confused when commas within quotes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
col1, col2, geometry
11.54000000,0.00000000,"{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-61.3115751786311,-33.83968838375797],[-61.29737019968823,-33.83207774370677],[-61.29443049860791,-33.83592770721248],[-61.29241347742871,-33.83489393774538],[-61.28994584513501,-33.83806650089736],[-61.292499308117186,-33.83938539699006],[-61.28958106470898,-33.8431993873636],[-61.29307859612687,-33.84495487100211],[-61.295256567865046,-33.846135537383866],[-61.296388484054326,-33.84676149889543],[-61.296747927196776,-33.84651421268175],[-61.297498943449426,-33.84670133707654],[-61.297992472179686,-33.847120134589964],[-61.299741220055196,-33.84901812154847],[-61.3012164422457,-33.85018089588664],[-61.3015892874819,-33.850566250375365],[-61.30284190607861,-33.85079121660985],[-61.30496105223345,-33.848193766906206],[-61.306084952130036,-33.84682375029292],[-61.30707604410075,-33.845532812572294],[-61.30672627175046,-33.84527169005647],[-61.306290670206494,-33.845188781884744],[-61.304604048903514,-33.847304098561025],[-61.30309763921784,-33.84654473836309],[-61.30013213880613,-33.84478736144466],[-61.30110629620797,-33.8431690707163],[-61.303046037678854,-33.844170576767105],[-61.30433047221653,-33.84266156764314],[-61.30484242472771,-33.842899106713375],[-61.30696068650711,-33.844104878773436],[-61.306418212892446,-33.84505221083753],[-61.307163201216696,-33.845464893960255],[-61.30760172622554,-33.84490909256552],[-61.307932962646014,-33.844513681420494],[-61.309176116985405,-33.84280834206188],[-61.30596211112515,-33.841126948963954],[-61.3056475423994,-33.841449215098756],[-61.30526859890979,-33.841557611902374],[-61.30483601097522,-33.84149669494795],[-61.30448925534122,-33.84120408616046],[-61.30410688411086,-33.840609953572034],[-61.30400151682434,-33.839925243738094],[-61.30240379835875,-33.83889223688216],[-61.30188418287129,-33.838444480832685],[-61.301130848179525,-33.83943255499186],[-61.30078636095504,-33.83996223583909],[-61.30059265818967,-33.84016469670277],[-61.30048478527255,-33.840438447848506],[-61.300252198180424,-33.84026774340676],[-61.29876711207748,-33.839489883020924],[-61.29799408649143,-33.840597902688785],[-61.297669258508,-33.84103160870988],[-61.297566592962134,-33.84112444052047],[-61.29748538503245,-33.841083604060834],[-61.297140578061956,-33.84134946797752],[-61.29709617977233,-33.84160419097128],[-61.297170540239335,-33.84168254110631],[-61.297341460506956,-33.84179653572337],[-61.297243418161194,-33.84197105818567],[-61.29699517169225,-33.84200300239938],[-61.29680176950715,-33.84179064473802],[-61.29691703393983,-33.8416707218475],[-61.297053755769845,-33.841604265738546],[-61.29707920124143,-33.84154875978832],[-61.29709391784669,-33.84147543150246],[-61.29711262215961,-33.84133768608576],[-61.296951411710374,-33.84119216012805],[-61.297262269660294,-33.84089514360839],[-61.297626491077864,-33.84051497848962],[-61.29865532547658,-33.83935363544152],[-61.30027710358755,-33.84011486145675],[-61.30046658230606,-33.83996490243917],[-61.30063460268783,-33.83979712050095],[-61.300992098665965,-33.8393813535522],[-61.301799802937595,-33.83832425565103],[-61.30135527704997,-33.837671541923235],[-61.30082030025984,-33.83731962483044],[-61.299512855628244,-33.83689640801839],[-61.29879550338594,-33.8363083288346],[-61.29831419490918,-33.835559835856905],[-61.298360098160686,-33.83408067231082],[-61.29976541168753,-33.83467181800819],[-61.30104200723692,-33.83586895614681],[-61.30133434017162,-33.83606352507277],[-61.30153415160492,-33.836339043812224],[-61.30164813329583,-33.83657891551336],[-61.30124575062752,-33.83743146168004],[-61.30195917352424,-33.83831965157767],[-61.30196183786503,-33.83843401993221],[-61.30250094586367,-33.83890484694379],[-61.304002690127376,-33.83984352469762],[-61.30473149692381,-33.8397514189025],[-61.3054487998093,-33.839941491549894],[-61.30582354557356,-33.84016574092716],[-61.30604808932503,-33.84046128014441],[-61.306143888278996,-33.840801374736316],[-61.30598219492593,-33.841088001849094],[-61.30757239940571,-33.841967156609876],[-61.30920555104759,-33.84277500140921],[-61.3115751786311,-33.83968838375797],[-61.3115751786311,-33.83968838375797]]]}"
```

How do I read a csv with syntax like above?

I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

However, `read_csv` gets confused with the `,` within `"{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":` I want it to ignore the `,` within the quotes.

Comment: I this it's caused by the wrong format of your csv file. The double quote (") in a cell should be escaped to this ("").

Comment: What is the source of this pooorly formatted CSV?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?  If not, please follow-up specifically so any outstanding concerns can be addressed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your *csv* file contains a *MultiIndex*, which is causing your read and split issues.

I have tried multiple methods to read your file correctly. The best method that I have found so far is using the Python engine with an advanced separator in the *read_csv* function.

```
import pandas as pd

# these are for viewing the output
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 30)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 120)

# The separator matches the format of the string that you provided.
# I'm sure that it can be modified to be more efficient.
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=1, sep='(\d{1,2}.\d{1,8}),(\d{1,2}.\d{1,8}),("{"type":.*)',engine="python")

# some cleanup
df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)

# I had to save the processed file
df.to_csv('test_01.csv')

# read in the new file
df = pd.read_csv('test_01.csv', header=None, index_col=0)
print(df.to_string(index=False))
11.54  0.0  "{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-61.3115751786311,-33.83968838375797],[-61.29737019968823,-33.83207774370677],[-61.29443049860791,-33.83592770721248],[-61.29241347742871,-33.83489393774538],[-61.28994584513501,-33.83806650089736],[-61.292499308117186,-33.83938539699006],[-61.28958106470898,-33.8431993873636],[-61.29307859612687,-33.84495487100211],[-61.295256567865046,-33.846135537383866],[-61.296388484054326,-33.84676149889543],[-61.296747927196776,-33.84651421268175],[-61.297498943449426,-33.84670133707654],[-61.297992472179686,-33.847120134589964],[-61.299741220055196,-33.84901812154847],[-61.3012164422457,-33.85018089588664],[-61.3015892874819,-33.850566250375365],[-61.30284190607861,-33.85079121660985],[-61.30496105223345,-33.848193766906206],[-61.306084952130036,-33.84682375029292],[-61.30707604410075,-33.845532812572294],[-61.30672627175046,-33.84527169005647],[-61.306290670206494,-33.845188781884744],[-61.304604048903514,-33.847304098561025],[-61.30309763921784,-33.84654473836309],[-61.30013213880613,-33.84478736144466],[-61.30110629620797,-33.8431690707163],[-61.303046037678854,-33.844170576767105],[-61.30433047221653,-33.84266156764314],[-61.30484242472771,-33.842899106713375],[-61.30696068650711,-33.844104878773436],[-61.306418212892446,-33.84505221083753],[-61.307163201216696,-33.845464893960255],[-61.30760172622554,-33.84490909256552],[-61.307932962646014,-33.844513681420494],[-61.309176116985405,-33.84280834206188],[-61.30596211112515,-33.841126948963954],[-61.3056475423994,-33.841449215098756],[-61.30526859890979,-33.841557611902374],[-61.30483601097522,-33.84149669494795],[-61.30448925534122,-33.84120408616046],[-61.30410688411086,-33.840609953572034],[-61.30400151682434,-33.839925243738094],[-61.30240379835875,-33.83889223688216],[-61.30188418287129,-33.838444480832685],[-61.301130848179525,-33.83943255499186],[-61.30078636095504,-33.83996223583909],[-61.30059265818967,-33.84016469670277],[-61.30048478527255,-33.840438447848506],[-61.300252198180424,-33.84026774340676],[-61.29876711207748,-33.839489883020924],[-61.29799408649143,-33.840597902688785],[-61.297669258508,-33.84103160870988],[-61.297566592962134,-33.84112444052047],[-61.29748538503245,-33.841083604060834],[-61.297140578061956,-33.84134946797752],[-61.29709617977233,-33.84160419097128],[-61.297170540239335,-33.84168254110631],[-61.297341460506956,-33.84179653572337],[-61.297243418161194,-33.84197105818567],[-61.29699517169225,-33.84200300239938],[-61.29680176950715,-33.84179064473802],[-61.29691703393983,-33.8416707218475],[-61.297053755769845,-33.841604265738546],[-61.29707920124143,-33.84154875978832],[-61.29709391784669,-33.84147543150246],[-61.29711262215961,-33.84133768608576],[-61.296951411710374,-33.84119216012805],[-61.297262269660294,-33.84089514360839],[-61.297626491077864,-33.84051497848962],[-61.29865532547658,-33.83935363544152],[-61.30027710358755,-33.84011486145675],[-61.30046658230606,-33.83996490243917],[-61.30063460268783,-33.83979712050095],[-61.300992098665965,-33.8393813535522],[-61.301799802937595,-33.83832425565103],[-61.30135527704997,-33.837671541923235],[-61.30082030025984,-33.83731962483044],[-61.299512855628244,-33.83689640801839],[-61.29879550338594,-33.8363083288346],[-61.29831419490918,-33.835559835856905],[-61.298360098160686,-33.83408067231082],[-61.29976541168753,-33.83467181800819],[-61.30104200723692,-33.83586895614681],[-61.30133434017162,-33.83606352507277],[-61.30153415160492,-33.836339043812224],[-61.30164813329583,-33.83657891551336],[-61.30124575062752,-33.83743146168004],[-61.30195917352424,-33.83831965157767],[-61.30196183786503,-33.83843401993221],[-61.30250094586367,-33.83890484694379],[-61.304002690127376,-33.83984352469762],[-61.30473149692381,-33.8397514189025],[-61.3054487998093,-33.839941491549894],[-61.30582354557356,-33.84016574092716],[-61.30604808932503,-33.84046128014441],[-61.306143888278996,-33.840801374736316],[-61.30598219492593,-33.841088001849094],[-61.30757239940571,-33.841967156609876],[-61.30920555104759,-33.84277500140921],[-61.3115751786311,-33.83968838375797],[-61.3115751786311,-33.83968838375797]]]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv',quotechar='"',skipinitialspace=True)
```